# How to source another .bashrc from root user

Tags: macos, terminal, root, bash

I normally use a User/account called "Jason", and I regularly update my .bashrc in that User. I occasionally use the root user in my computer (I use a MacBook), and it is highly annoying that my .bashrc is not accessible there. Is there any way I can have the root user automatically source the .bashrc located in the "Jason" user?

I tried simply putting "source Users/Jason/.bashrc" in the root .bashrc, but that didn't work. The error was that the file does not exist; my problem is that the root user is located in /var/root/ and I am trying to source /Users/Jason/. Is there any way I can get past that?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm an idiot. I was missing a slash. "source /Users/Jason/.bashrc" works.

Comment: You are missing a slash. `source /Users/Jason/.bashrc`.

Comment: By the way, I'd like to mention that this is very bad practice. It basically allows a privilege escalation attack: unprivileged process write to your `~/.bashrc`, then commands get to run as root when you open an interactive root shell.

Comment: I figured out my mistake soon after submitting the question lol. I felt like such an idiot. As for your other point, what else do you recommend? Is there any other way to use automatically load my normal .bashrc when using the root user?

Comment: "Is there any other way to automatically load..." The point is automatically loading your normal `.bashrc` is not safe. What I do for my zsh runcoms (same applies to bash and other shells) is to manage them in a dotfile repository, and symlink them into HOME. Then I would clone a copy in root user's home also. Every time my runcoms change, I push them to, say, GitHub, which I can pull later from a root shell. This way, every single change requires your explicit involvement and consent, and there's no way malicious code can be injected.

Comment: In case this is done, it would be a good idea to run `chmod 600 /root/.bashrc` so that anything unpriviledged cannot know that this is happening. But of course, this is security through obscurity.

Answer (score -2):

Use `sudo bash`, which starts a new shell with your `.bashrc` but runs it as `root`.

Comment: Thanks for the information - I didn't know that. But it doesn't really answer my question.